# Calling a model from a controller from the 404 route

Tags: php, codeigniter

Got a problem here where I can’t seem to load a method from a model after the page has been redirected after encountering a 404.

Model name: `Category_Model`
Method name: `get_category_menu()`

In my routes, I’ve updated the 404 over-ride to: `$route[‘404_override’] = ‘whoops’;`

I’ve also got my controller Whoops that reads:-

```
<?php
class Whoops extends CI_Controller 
{
  function index()
  {
    $this->load->model('Category_Model');
    $data['Categories'] = $this->Category_Model->get_category_menu();
    $data['main_content'] = $this->load->view('messages/whoops', null, true);
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
  }
}
```

So when I navigate to a page that doesn’t exist, I get the following error…

Message: `Undefined property: Whoops::$Category_Model`
Filename: `controllers/whoops.php`

I’ve hard coded the loading of the model into the controller here, even though I have it in my autoload, but no luck.

Everything else with the site so far works, just this 404 problem.  Any pointers would be great, kinda new to CI so go easy on me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried constructing the parent?

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

function index()...
```

Comment: Nope, the issue was with the version in the end.  I was using 2.0.1, upgraded the system folder to the latest (2.1.0) and this issue has resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's some code in the model that requires it, you should be able to get away with calling the method as a static method.  Just make sure to prefix get_category_menu() with 'static' in the Category_Model.

```
function index()
  {
    $this->load->model('Category_Model');
    $data['Categories'] = Category_Model::get_category_menu();
    $data['main_content'] = $this->load->view('messages/whoops', null, true);
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
  }
```